# What are the differences between a "dissimilarity matrix" and a "distance matrix"?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, similar-matrices

**QUESTION.** What are the differences between a "dissimilarity matrix" and a "distance matrix"?
Do they share the same properties, or not?
In case, can you show an example?

If there is any difference among these two matrices, to me, that difference is **not** clear when I read these two references:

- Encyclopedia of Distances, by Michel Marie Deza and Elena Deza
- Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics, by James E. Gentle

**EDITED 1.** "Dissimilarity matrix" from Encyclopedia of Distances, by Michel Marie Deza and Elena Deza

[image]

**EDITED 2.** "Dissimilarity matrix" from Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics, by James E. Gentle

[image]

Comment: You could make the question more self-contained by including the definitions of dissimilarity matrix and of distance matrix.

Comment: a great difference is for example: the name ;)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt many readers will track down the definitions in those references, but I can give you my take on the terms.  Neither strikes me has having a universally agreed-upon definition.  "Distance matrix" is close, however:  an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries $d_{ij}$ form a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  In particular, the $d_{ij}$ must obey the triangle inequality:  $d_{ij} + d_{jk} \ge d_{ik}$.  However, if an author allows an off-diagonal $d_{ij} = 0$ in their distance matrix, that seems reasonable:  calling this a "semi-distance matrix" seems too pedantic.

On the other hand, the term "dissimilarity matrix" is much vaguer.  If I encountered this term, I'd expect the matrix to be zero on the diagonal and positive otherwise.
I'd expect the matrix to be symmetric, but I wouldn't be too surprised if it weren't.  I wouldn't expect the triangle inequality to hold.  I might expect there to be a similarity matrix to be defined with entries in $[0,1]$ and a dissimilarity matrix to be one minus this.

In short, some terms in mathematics, such as "group" or "real number" have universally agreed-upon definitions.  "Distance matrix" is close to having one, but "dissimilarity matrix" is not.  The latter is more of a description of how to think about the elements of a matrix than a definition of a type of matrix.  Of course, authors are always free to define what they mean by "dissimilarity matrix" or any other term.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JimFerry!!! :-) What if I have a matrix that is (i) symmetric, (ii) square, (iii) has all the diagonal elements equal to zero, (iv) all the off-diagonal are either positive or zero, and (v) the elements of the matrix result from, either divergence measures or distance measures, among two probability distributions, P and Q (e.g. the Hellinger distance H(P, Q), or the Jensen–Shannon divergence, JSD(P,Q))?

Comment: Hmm.  Yes, there's a distinction between matrices that arise from some structure such as a distance or a divergence and those that are defined in a more ad hoc manner.  Not sure what to say about it.  Those that arise from a structure will inherit the properties of that structure.  Distance is a nice, symmetric structure.  Divergence is a useful structure to compare, say, an estimated probability distribution to the true distribution, but is not symmetric.

Comment: If I understood correctly, a distance matrix should have some of the properties I have listed for my matrix, i.e. properties (i) symmetric, (iii) the entries on the main diagonal are all zero, (iv) all the off-diagonal entries are positive, and (vi) the triangle inequality holds...

Comment: Yes.  The best way to think of a distance matrix is as defining a metric on a finite set of points (i.e., the points $1$ through $n$ that index the matrix's rows and columns).   Thus the properties that define a metric carry over directly into being properties of the matrix.